# SAML Unable to resolve binding type, invalid or unsupported http request

Tags: php, symfony, single-sign-on, saml

I have an error implementing SSO with SAML on Symfony2.
Im using http://www.lightsaml.com/ bundle for symfony.

The actual problem is:

- I can login fine the first time.
- Once the user close the window, open it again and try to login, i got the following error.

> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] request.INFO: Matched route "lightsaml_sp.login_check" (parameters: "_route": "lightsaml_sp.login_check") [] []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] security.DEBUG: Username "XXXXX     " was reloaded from user provider. [] []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] app.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve binding type, invalid or unsupported http request {"profile_id":"sso_sp_receive_response","own_role":"sp","action":"LightSaml\Action\Profile\Inbound\Message\ReceiveMessageAction","top_context_id":"00000000798ef05100007f47549bc045","top_context":{"http_request":[],"own_entity":[]}} []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LightSaml\Error\LightSamlBindingException: "Unable to resolve binding type, invalid or unsupported http request" at /home/riosuper/subdomains/espana/releases/20160125140200/vendor/lightsaml/lightsaml/src/LightSaml/Action/Profile/Inbound/Message/ReceiveMessageAction.php line 52 {"exception":"[object] (LightSaml\Error\LightSamlBindingException(code: 0): Unable to resolve binding type, invalid or unsupported http request at /home/riosuper/subdomains/espana/releases/20160125140200/vendor/lightsaml/lightsaml/src/LightSaml/Action/Profile/Inbound/Message/ReceiveMessageAction.php:52)"} []
>
> [2016-01-27 05:55:42] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
>
> --

Im completely lost on what is going on.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you please format your question? Here is a starting point if you need one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: What's your config/security.yml? How do you "try to login"? The route "lightsaml_sp.login_check" is the one receiving SAML Response from IDP, and the error message means lightsaml could not find the Response in the HTTP request neither in POST nor GET variables.